# "...nowhere a programme like this one taught." or "...nowhere taught a programme like this one."

Tags: inversion

Which sentence is right? For me, both sentences sounds right...

- In Austria there is nowhere a programme like this one taught.
- In Austria there is nowhere taught a programme like this one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can say "In Austria there is nowhere a programme like this one." *Taught* at the end of the sentence doesn't make sense. "There is nowhere taught a programme" doesn't make sense too.

You can say a programme is not taught in Austria, and in that case the sentence would be similar to the following one.

> In Austria, a programme like this one is not taught.

I would use the following sentence.

> In Austria there isn't a [school] programme like this one.

I would say "school programme" if I want to be sure it is clear of which programme I am talking. If that is clear from the context, I would simply say *programme* instead of "school programme."

Comment: i want to say that the programme i found at a college in london, is nowhere available in austria...

Comment: That is the meaning of the last sentence. I assume you talk of the programme you found at a college in London in a previous sentence.

Comment: Your first expression does not make any sense. I don't think I have ever seen 'taught programme', and even if it is correct, it is certainly not a natural/simple way to say what OP wants to say.

Comment: @Thor I should have been clearer: I have never said the first sentence was correct, nor that it made any sense. I am just showing how to get a better sentence, which is the last one in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say

> In Austria, there is no place/college/school where a program like this is taught(offered?).

or

> In Austria, this program is not offered anywhere.

or

> In Austria, this program is offered nowhere.

Please note that the last expression is something I will see in movies, but I think 2nd expression is more natural that 3rd one.